# <init> method at run time

Tags: java, reflection, init

Im trying to find `<init>` method. I have the following class:

```
public class Node<T>{ }
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(Method m: new Node().getClass().getMethods()){
            System.out.println(m.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
public final void java.lang.Object.wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public final native void java.lang.Object.wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)
public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()
public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()
public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
public final native void java.lang.Object.notify()
public final native void java.lang.Object.notifyAll()
```

This class has default constructor. Hence this constructor must be trasformed default constructor to method `<init>` when `Node` will be compiled. Why i cant see him at run time?

Comment: Because it is still considered as a `Constructor`, not a `Method`.

Comment: this is just how `Class.getMethods()` works. If you use `javap` tool, it show you constructors, though named after class (as in source code) rather than `<init>`. Its easy to create particular classfile parser (there are many supporting libraries) that will give you both methods and constructors in single array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get `Constructor` instances

```
for (Constructor constructor : new Test().getClass().getConstructors()) {
    System.out.println(constructor);
}
```

prints

```
public test.Test() // In this case, com.yourpackage.Node() for your class
```

Comment: Is it true that JVM can be difference normal method from constructor at run time? I thinked that constructor is method who called when we create a new instance (i.e. for JVM constructor just a method).

Comment: @St.Antario Of course, otherwise you could just call `Node()` as if it was a method.

Comment: @St.Antario What you are referring to is at the JVM level. You aren't programming at that level.

Comment: I dont completely understand you. Compiler can be difference constructor from just method. When we create a new instance compiler checked for existence of corresponding contructor. Now when our class was compiled for JVM constructor is just a method. _At the level of the Java Virtual Machine, every constructor written in the Java programming language (JLS §8.8) appears as an instance initialization method that has the special name <init>._ Hence we can see him at run time. Where my reason is incorrect?

Comment: @St.Antario The JVM can see it as a method at run time. Your application however still sees it as a constructor.

Comment: _You aren't programming at that level._ Does it mean that at run time we cant access to JVM's internal methods, but can use methods who desribed in the source code of our class?

Comment: @St.Antario Yes, that is what I meant. You are writing a Java application as described by the Java Language Specification. The JVM is just a tool to support that application.